# “Run this job” based on value in angular.json in Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is there any way to stop the Azure CI/CD pipeline bases on the values in angular.json

[image]

I need to run the pipeline only when "defaultProject" contains 'pos-ac-pos' which is in angular.json file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a script task to check the value of `defaultProject`. If the value is not `pos-ac-pos`, you can stop the pipeline manually. For below example in powershell script:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   $angular = (Get-Content "$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/angular.json" -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json
   
   if ($angular.defaultProject -ne "pos-ac-pos"){
   
     exit 1
   }
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

If you add a powershell task to run above script in your pipeline. When the defaultProject isnot pos-ac-pos. The task will fail and stop the pipeline.

You can also create new pipeline as a triggering pipeline with above script task to check the value of `defaultProject`. And trigger your main pipeline by using [Trigger Build task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks&targetId=47097972-e633-4284-ad72-fe49f3c8dd5f) Or using [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1), if the script task succeed. See below example:

```
steps:
    - powershell: |
       $angular = (Get-Content "$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/angular.json" -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json
       
       if ($angular.defaultProject -ne "pos-ac-pos"){
       
         exit 1
       }
      displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
   
   - task: benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks.trigger-build-task.TriggerBuild@3
     displayName: 'Trigger a new build of 12'
     inputs:
       buildDefinition: 12
```

Note: You might need to disable the CI trigger of the main pipeline. For it will be triggered by the new triggering pipeline.